# How to check if a solr query will return data before actually loading the data?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I'm about to write some code that will run numerous solr queries. But I wont need to load the documents from these queries every time I run the query. I mean, I may run 6 queries but I may need to load the documents from the 5th query **only**.

So to speed things up, is there a way to run a solr query that would only return a value indicating if this query will return documents or not ? My aim is not to load documents unless I will actually use them. Just to speed up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 ways to achieve that :

- Using `fl` parameter you can set a field list to return : set an empty string, or set a field name that does not exist in your index so that the request doesn't fallback to the default field list. It should return a list of *empty* documents :

  ```
  SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
  query.setQuery("something to search");
  query.set("fl", "unknown_field");
  SolrDocumentList out = server.query(query).getResults();
  ```
- using `rows` parameter (should be preferred), ask solr to return 0 document :

  ```
  query.setRows(0); 
  server.query(query).getResults();
  ```

In both cases `getNumFound()` method should return the number of matched documents.

Comment: Doesn't `getResults()` return the document list ? (i.e. loads the documents matched by the query) I don't want to load the documents, I only need to find out if the query can return documents but not actually load the documents from the core.

Comment: I updated my answer. Actually, it returns a list with a given number of matched docs, but they should be empty. You can get the number of matched documents with `out.getNumFound()`. Check that `out.get(someindex).size()` returns 0 to be sure nothing was loaded.

Comment: `setRows(0)` is the way to go